# How can I get better debugging and error messages with Karma and Jasmine tests?

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I just created a new angular project from [ngbp](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) template. I wanted to use angular-material, and was getting some angular conflicts (material needs 1.4.7 and angular-bootstrap 1.3.x).

So I removed all dependencies from the bower.json file and started from scratch, adding angular-material first, then angular, then ui-router.

So far so good.

When I run grunt to build, I get karma error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 ERROR (0.001 secs / 0 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:continuous" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

So I deleted all tests and now I get:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.001 secs / 0 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:continuous" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

So now I have no error messages, and nothing to go on. How do I debug this?

Comment: Error is hidden within `karma:continuous` task in your grunt file. Pretty lack of details to answer.

Comment: @Appeiron Can you elaborate? How do I unhide it?

Comment: Can you find `GruntFile.js` that is actually configuration for `grunt`? There should be something like 'karma: { ... }' - that's configuration of `grunt-karma` task. Error can be in configuration of that one.

Comment: @Appeiron I don't see any error configuration...

Comment: Error **in** configuration of task named _karma_.